# Error saving entity changes: An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Whenever I attempt to run the following code, i always get this error:

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.
>   The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same
>   key.

Here is my code

```
// find assessmentcase that needs to be updated
var CaseToBeUpdated = db.AssessmentCases
                     .Where(c => c.CaseSeq == score.CaseSeq)
                     .FirstOrDefault();

// create new assessmentcase with updated data                    
AssessmentCase assessmentcase = new AssessmentCase
                                {
                                    CaseSeq = CaseToBeUpdated.CaseSeq,
                                    DateClosed = System.DateTime.Now,
                                    SeqClosedBy = SeqClosedBy,
                                    UserIdClosed = User.Identity.Name,
                                };

// save changes to assessment case table
db.Entry(assessmentcase).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Essentially, I'm trying to update some data in the `assessmentcase` table. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the first line you load the entity to memory so EF starts to track it. Then you create another entity with the same CaseSeq (which I believe is a primary key) and then you try to attached it to EF. So you have 2 entities with the same primary key. Don't create new object. Use the one you loaded from memory.

```
// find assessmentcase that needs to be updated
var CaseToBeUpdated = db.AssessmentCases
                     .Where(c => c.CaseSeq == score.CaseSeq)
                     .FirstOrDefault();

CaseToBeUpdated.DateClosed = System.DateTime.Now;
CaseToBeUpdated.SeqClosedBy = SeqClosedBy;
CaseToBeUpdated.UserIdClosed = User.Identity.Name;

// save changes to assessment case table
db.Entry(CaseToBeUpdated).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 2):

why do you not simply update the retrieved record?

```
var CaseToBeUpdated = db.AssessmentCases
                 .Where(c => c.CaseSeq == score.CaseSeq)
                 .FirstOrDefault();

// create new assessmentcase with updated data                    
CaseToBeUpdated.DateClosed = System.DateTime.Now;
CaseToBeUpdated.SeqClosedBy = SeqClosedBy;
CaseToBeUpdated.UserIdClosed = User.Identity.Name;

// this should not be necessary ...   
db.Entry(CaseToBeUpdated).State = EntityState.Modified;
// save changes to assessment case table
db.SaveChanges();
```